# What is this error "Java.Lang.NoSuchFieldException: 'No field mDefaultTextColor in class Landroid/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout;"?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

This happened after updating Xamarin.forms, installing the latest xamarin.forms.visuals.material and switching to VS 19 from 17. Target sdk is 28 with a minimum of 21. Happens while trying to navigate to a page.

```
Java.Lang.NoSuchFieldException
  Message=No field mDefaultTextColor in class Landroid/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout; (declaration of 'android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout' appears in /data/app/...)
```

Comment: Does the app crash, or is this just a message you see in the output? Does it only happen navigating to a particular page, or all pages? You may need to supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Jimmy, I use Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material 4.2.0.709249 version, have no issue, so you can try to install this version.

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT  thank you for the help. I unfortunately could not provide you with a demo hence my delay, but I did fix it. Check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that an older library that was being used in the project was causing the issue. Its called Xfx.Controls. It was being used on the Entry control in only one of the pages and I'm guessing it was using an old field "mDefaultTextColor".

My fix was just to remove the library as I believe it has not been updated to support new Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I am glad to see you have solved your issue by yourself, so please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using design library v28.0.0 and later, fields had changed from `mDefaultTextColor` to `defaultHintTextColor` and from `mFocusedTextColor` to `focusedTextColor`.